# Bootstrap 3.2.0 Glyphicons not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I'm new to bootstrap & its glyphicons are not working for me. After I've inspect the code, `font-family` of `glyphicon-user` was `"Helvetica Neue",​Helvetica,​Arial,​sans-serif` & not `Glyphicons Halflings`. Am I missing something or do i need to change the `css` file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon-user"></span>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount">
                <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="US Dollar">
                <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add the class `glyphicon`.

So your span should actually be:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
```

As shown in the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use

Comment: If the OP spent 10 seconds reading the documentation he'd have known this. +1

Comment: Thanks, so sorry for my careless question.

Answer (score 3):

It's not enough to name the glyph, you have to use the class `glyphicon` too.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
```

Also, beware if you are using this in Opera mobile emulator. It doesn't support these fonts properly so you'll get a blank square.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps to work Glyphicons icons in your boostrap project:

1. add fonts folder to your project from recently downloaded from http://getbootstrap.com and below code for sample

```html
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
```

[image]

Thanks!