# Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons Not Showing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My Bootstrap Glyphicons are not showing up for some reason.

I have tried the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369036/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-not-working), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245575/bootstrap-3-unable-to-display-glyphicon-properly), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466519/bootstrap-3-2-0-glyphicons-not-working), and [here](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/bootstrap-glyphicon-not-displaying-question)

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div class="service-wrapper">
     <h2 class="pricing-plan-title">Plan</h2>
     <span class="glyphicon glyhpicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <p>Praesent rhoncus mauris ac sollicitudin vehicula. Nam fringilla turpis turpis</p>
</div>
```

Can anybody see what I am missing?

Comment: As you can see, it's not showing up in this fiddle, but the cloud is.  Maybe the pencil is not a valid icon. http://jsfiddle.net/Godisgood/8175t4uc/

Comment: Downvote for a typo? Harsh...

Comment: Thanks for evening out that downvote kind stranger! LoL

Comment: Love your user name BTW. God IS good. All the time!

Comment: And all the time . . .

Comment: @AllenLevings, the downvote was neither "for a typo" nor "harsh". It *was* because `This question does not show any research effort`.  There was no good faith attempt to format your question to make readable for anybody else.  There was little attempt to take the effort of removing code one by one to see what was breaking your code.  There was no attempt to look up the documentation and see what the official usage of of the symbol was.  I'm not saying this to be a jerk, but so you truly understand the way members of this community often vote so you can compose better questions in the future.

Comment: I understand the typo was a dummy mistake,  but to say no research? Did I not provide 4 links as to things I tried? I am not buying it. Sorry man. I will keep your advice for future reference however.

Comment: @AllenLevings, linking to other questions is a good start, but that was researching *other people's* problems, not your own. If something was wrong with the glyphicon, why not test a page that only had the code `<span class="glyphicon glyhpicon-pencil" ></span>`. Then if it wasn't working, just include that in your question. Then prove to everyone else why it should be working by linking to the docs (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-glyphs) to show you're using the right thing.  By this point in the investigation, 90% people have solved the problem on their own. Plus Formatting!

Comment: Downvote for formatting? C'mon Kyle! It is obvious I am still new here so some advice would have gone farther than a downvote. And I am still not buying your research excuse. Not useful to other members of the community I can accept,  but research? Either way,  it is what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to correct your spelling from `glyhpicon` to `glyphicon`:

```
<!-- From: --> <span class="glyphicon glyhpicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<!-- To:   --> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Comment: Man! Even after you told me the problem it took me 5 minutes to find the typo! 10 straight hours I suppose is enough. It is clearly time to take a break...  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo in your code.

In the `glyphicon-pencil`, the word *glyphicon* is wrongly typed.

**Try this**

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Comment: @Macsupport: Ya buddy :)